# VS 2010 student purchase?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to purchase the VS 2010 Professional Edition, but I'm also looking for a info if maybe there is a discount for students ?

### Edit

The regular price is about 800$ but [here](http://www.academicsuperstore.com/products/Microsoft/Visual+Studio/1387985) I can buy it only for 104.95$ Does it not look to you suspicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DREAM SPARK account, you can get Visual Studio 2010 Professional for free. Or just get registered your self [Visit Dream Spark Website for free registration](http://www.dreamspark.com)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can't use it for a commercial purpose

Comment: if you want to use it for commercial purpose. then you cant get any student discount.